# How to run Openedge explorer?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I am new to Progress and have the Progress OE 12.2 developer Kit classroom version. Try to create an OpenEdge explorer connection using the studio and get the following error message.

"The version of OpenEdge Explorer service running at localhost:9090 does not support this request"

Is it the issue from the software version or else?

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwXsH.png)

Comment: This looks like it might be the same question as asked at https://community.progress.com/s/question/0D54Q0000ACUMYjSQP/how-to-run-openedge-explorer . If so, someone from Progress will ahve to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple versions of OpenEdge running? If so please disable autostart of all the other OpenEdge Admin Servers, restart and try again.

[image]